# Slow performance on joining table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, innodb

I am trying to optimize a query as below , I have study how to add index to improve peformance , but the result is still slow. The query below took 20 sec to run , Transaction contains around 100k records and joining table TransactionDetail that contains around 500k records.

```
    SELECT Transaction.id ....
    FROM Transaction
    INNER JOIN Agent ON Agent.id = Transaction.agent_id
    INNER JOIN Distributor ON Distributor.id = Transaction.distributor_id
    INNER JOIN TransactionDetail ON Transaction.id = TransactionDetail.transaction_id
    WHERE TransactionDetail.type =  'Admin'
    AND Transaction.status IN ('pending',  'processing',  'success',  'rejected')
    ORDER BY issued_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

from the query above I try to apply what I understand about indexing

1. I added 3 index because of the inner join ,
   Transaction(agent_id,distributor_id) and Transaction(transaction_id)
2. From the where clause I added Transaction(status)
3. Because of ORDER BY I added Transaction(issued_date)

But it doesn't show any improvement below is what I get from EXPLAIN

[image]

And this is screenshot from phpmyadmin that show indexing for table Transaction

[image]

Is there any way to improvement this query? Or it is already optimised and I should focus on mysql configuration?

Comment: Please do write me a comment if you think I should add in more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query

```
SELECT Transaction.id ....
FROM Transaction
INNER JOIN Agent ON Agent.id = Transaction.agent_id
INNER JOIN Distributor ON Distributor.id = Transaction.distributor_id
INNER JOIN TransactionDetail ON Transaction.id = TransactionDetail.transaction_id
WHERE TransactionDetail.type =  'Admin'
AND Transaction.status IN ('pending',  'processing',  'success',  'rejected')
ORDER BY issued_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Now you already have indexes applied on the tables which is good, however the `in clause` is more like `or`
and this creates a real performance issue. In case of small data-set this could not be observed but in large data-set
the performance will be dropped significantly.

One method of optimizing it would be to convert the `in clause` into `union` which works better than `or` `in`

```
(
 SELECT Transaction.id ....
 FROM Transaction
 INNER JOIN Agent ON Agent.id = Transaction.agent_id
 INNER JOIN Distributor ON Distributor.id = Transaction.distributor_id
 INNER JOIN TransactionDetail ON Transaction.id = TransactionDetail.transaction_id
 WHERE TransactionDetail.type =  'Admin'
 AND Transaction.status = 'pending'
)
union
(
 SELECT Transaction.id ....
 FROM Transaction
 INNER JOIN Agent ON Agent.id = Transaction.agent_id
 INNER JOIN Distributor ON Distributor.id = Transaction.distributor_id
 INNER JOIN TransactionDetail ON Transaction.id = TransactionDetail.transaction_id
 WHERE TransactionDetail.type =  'Admin'
 AND Transaction.status = 'processing'
)
union
(
 SELECT Transaction.id ....
 FROM Transaction
 INNER JOIN Agent ON Agent.id = Transaction.agent_id
 INNER JOIN Distributor ON Distributor.id = Transaction.distributor_id
 INNER JOIN TransactionDetail ON Transaction.id = TransactionDetail.transaction_id
 WHERE TransactionDetail.type =  'Admin'
 AND Transaction.status = 'success'
)
union
(
 SELECT Transaction.id ....
 FROM Transaction
 INNER JOIN Agent ON Agent.id = Transaction.agent_id
 INNER JOIN Distributor ON Distributor.id = Transaction.distributor_id
 INNER JOIN TransactionDetail ON Transaction.id = TransactionDetail.transaction_id
 WHERE TransactionDetail.type =  'Admin'
 AND Transaction.status = 'rejected'
)
order by issued_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

For resolving the order by you may need to add the index as

```
alter table Transaction add index status_created_idx(status,issued_date);
```

Comment: That's great except that this IS a small data set.

Comment: @Strawberry for small set of data having indexes on the `status` and `issued_date` could resolve the issue, even for 100 thousand records I can tell you the result should be returned in `0.2` sec max.

Comment: You missed one part `issued_date` in order by ;) rest all 100% agree.

Comment: I have try to rewrite my code , but it show little improvement , is there any other way to improve it?

Comment: You may try your original query but make sure you have an index as `alter table Transaction add index status_created_idx(status,issued_date);` Take a backup of the table and apply the index and then see the performance.

Comment: The proposed unions and index are useless for the following reasons.  Each `SELECT` in the `UNION` will pick its own index, but it won't pick `(status, issue_date)` because (1) `issue_date` is not in the `SELECT` and `status` has low cardinality.  Hence I predict the union will be slower than the original.

Answer (score 1):

Adding all the `INDEXes` is futile since the optimizer will (almost always) use only one index.

The original query *might* benefit from `INDEX(issue_date)`.  Add that index, then show us the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see if it is using it.

If it is using it, that will only benefit by avoiding a "filesort", which is usually only a small portion of the total time.  It may also benefit from stopping due to `LIMIT`.  However, it will probably have to read more than 10 rows, since the `WHERE` includes other tables.

Because of `TransactionDetail.type =  'Admin'`, it has to work its way through the `JOINs` before deciding what row(s) to keep.

Two questions that *may* lead to other options:

- What percent of the rows of TransactionDetail have type =  'Admin'?
- What percent of the rows of Transaction have have status IN ('pending',  'processing',  'success',  'rejected')?

As you are experimenting, post (1) the indexes and (2) the EXPLAIN.